# Problem while installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside to Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

Windows 10 installed on my computer and I am trying to dual-boot it with Ubuntu 16.04. To do this, I shrank 100GB volume on Windows, disabled secure boot from BIOS and made USB flash drive bootable. But, when installation window appeared, after selecting language and wifi connection, the following appears:
[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PLCv.png)

The volume of flash drive is 4GB. Maybe installer thinks that flash drive is the environment where Ubuntu must be, or not?

Comment: Is your Windows installed in legacy mode?  That would have to be on a DOS partitioned disk, and there is a max of four primary partitions. If you already have 4, and no extended partition with room for logical partitions, then you have to backup/remove a partition, make an extended partition, then the installer can see a place to make logical partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually select the right partition to install Ubuntu to, during the installation process, as outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/343370/21008).

Also, maybe consider installing Ubuntu 20.04, which is the newest version. Ubuntu 16.04 is only supported until next year.

Comment: Your solution is the case when I have an opportunity to choose how to distribute my hard disk storage. But, in my case, I can't even do this; in the third stage of installation, the above window comes up. Installer doesn't allow me to contunie installing.
By the way, my laptop is Acer Extensa-15, does it matter?

Comment: Hm, so the installer doesn't see your harddrive/partition. What happens if you use gparted in the live environment? Can you see your partitions? If yes, can you use gparted to format the free space you created in Windows as ext4.